# browser showing loading even after executing con.query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, google-chrome, backend

I have the code below:

```
app.post('/add', function(req,res){

  let addcar = req.body.car;
  let addnumber = req.body.number;

  var ssql = "SELECT 1 from cardata where email = '" + addcar + "' or number = '" + addnumber + "'";

  con.query(ssql, function (err, result, fields) {
    
    if(result[0]){
      console.log("Number or Email Already Exists!")
    }
    else{
      var sql = "INSERT INTO cardata (car, number) VALUES ('" + addcar + "' , '" + addnumber + "')";
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Whenever I run node server.js, the code works fine and does what it is supposed to. However, the browser shows that the page is still loading even after the record has been inserted into the db. Is there anyway I can end the program to make it stop loading?

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image: Screenshot][image: Loading Bar]

Comment: My phone number is `'; DELETE TABLE cardata; --` You got SQL injection all over this

Comment: its just for a project lol @Charlieface

Comment: do you know how to solve it?